# Vercel doesn't include host nor origin

Tags: vercel

So this is my middleware that tags the request and the request doesnt contain host nor origin nor nothing from the reqeusted origin, so I can't setup cors for this reason, how is this possible, locally no.

```
import cors from 'nextjs-cors'

import { ALLOWED_ORIGINS } from '../configs/Envs'

const Cors = async (req, res) => {
    const ORIGINS = ALLOWED_ORIGINS.split(',')
    
    console.log({
        host: req.headers['host'],
        origin: req.headers['origin'],
        referer: req.headers['referer'],
        xforwardedHost: req.headers['x-forwarded-host'],
        req: req.headers
    })

    if (ORIGINS.includes('*')) {
        await cors(req, res, {
            methods: '*',
            origin: '*',
            optionsSuccessStatus: 200
        })

        return true
    }

    else {
        const ORIGIN = req.headers['origin'] || req.headers['host']

        if (ORIGINS.includes(ORIGIN)) {
            await cors(req, res, {
                methods: '*',
                origin: ORIGIN,
                optionsSuccessStatus: 200
            })
            
            return true
        }
    
        else return false
    }
}

export default Cors
```

I tried forwarding host but nothing not even property in header includes the host, I have no exports or API settings also.

I tried to check all origins